# How to print to STDERR in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

The `println` function writes to `STDOUT`. How can we write messages to `STDERR` instead?

```
(println "Hello, STDOUT!")
```

Answer (score 35):

There is no specific function for this, however you can dynamically rebind the var holding the stream that `println` writes to like this:

```
(println "Hello, STDOUT!")

(binding [*out* *err*]
  (println "Hello, STDERR!"))
```

In my REPL, the colour indicates the stream (red is STDERR):

[image]

Comment: Which repl are you using?

Comment: @KobbyPemson Btw, the upcoming Cider 0.6 also highlights differently STDOUT and STDERR output in the REPL.

Answer (score 24):

Plain Java methods work fine and will be understood easily by Clojure novices:

```
(.println *err* "Hello, STDERR!")
```

Another alternative, just for fun, is `clojure.java.io/copy`:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as cjio])

(cjio/copy "Hello, STDERR!\n" *err*)
(.flush *err*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're logging, another option is the use of a logging library, such as [clojure/tools.logging](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging). This offers a nice syntax:

```
(require [clojure.tools.logging :as log])
(log/error "There was an error here")
```

It also provides some formatting features, and `spy` functions that are like trace, but can be given various log levels.